# Самый быстрый способ определения НОД всех элементов множества

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Для решения задачи необходимо найти НОД множества. Может кто-либо предоставить код, или алгоритм, чтобы сделать это достаточно быстро.

Дополнительный вопрос: изначальная задача - найти числа, при деление  на которые все элементы множества дают одинаковый остаток. Можно ли найти такие числа быстрее, чем перебором чисел от 2 до НОД всех элементов множества разностей изначального множества?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 - НОД - наибольший общий делитель.

Алгоритм для поиска НОД 2 чисел известен, но приведу его ещё раз.

```
long long gcd(long long a,long long b){
    while (a && b)
        if (a > b) a%=b;
        else b%=a;
    return a+b; 
}
```

Тут используется допущение, что `НОД(0,0)=0`, это часто удобно.

Теперь, чтобы найти НОД нескольких чисел, нужно последовательно брать НОД от них.

```
 long long gcd(const vector<long long>& num){
    if (num.size() == 0)
       return 0;
    if (num.size() == 1)
       return num[0];
    long long res = gcd(num[0],num[1]);
    for (auto i=2;i<num.size() && res!=1;i++)  //&& res!=1 можно не писать
         res = gcd(res,num[i]);
 }
```

> найти числа, при деление на которые все элементы множества дают
>   одинаковый остаток.

Есть разные варианты, как это сделать. НО идея у вас перебирать от 2 до НОД неправильная. Пример: 5 и 9 дают остаток 1 при делении на 4. Но НОД(5,9)=1.

Если в наборе более 1 числа (предполагаю что все числа *различны*) то количество таких делителей будет не больше чем минимальное из этих чисел. Но это долго.

Пусть `x = a*p + r, y = b*p + r`  Тогда `x-y = (b-a)*p` И значит делится на `p` аналогично для остальных пар. Поэтому ответ - все делители от НОД **разностей** всех чисел (Их N^2, но все необязательны, достаточно между соседними или от 1 ко всем, всего N-1 штука).

Доказательство. Пусть `G = gcd(delt)`.

Тогда если `x ≡ r (mod G). y = x + (y - x) => y = x + G*q => y ≡ r + G*q (mod G) => y ≡ r (mod G).` Что и требовалось.

В обратную: `для любых (x,y) x ≡ r (mod Q) y ≡ r (mod Q) G not | Q => x-y ≡ 0 (mod Q) => x-y делится на Q. Отсюда противоречие с тем что G - gcd();`

Реализацию сами допишите.

Сложность - память `O(n)` или `O(1)` время `O(n * log2(M) + sqrt(M) )`. где  M - максимальное значение. `sqrt(M)` - факторизация ответа, можно и без неё алгоритмы найти легко.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ на оба вопроса.
Но на счет моей идеи : я предлагал перебирать числа от 2 до НОД _разностей_ элементов, но, видимо, недостаточно четко это написал, что и вызвало непонимание.
И еще возник вопрос: разность можно считать подряд и брать ее по модулю, или стоит предварительно отсортировать массив, чтобы сэкономить время при последующих подсчетах?

Comment: @Ka_ktus разницы нет, я написал можете хоть от максимального ко всем брать, как вам удобно. Можете чуть алгоритм НОД изменить чтобы с отрицательными работало.

Answer (score 1):

НОД можно найти по алгоритму Эвклида. Он прекрасно работает для более чем 2ух чисел.

Comment: Реализовать алгоритм можно так: хранить множество в куче(в вершине должен быть максимальный элемент множества); создать цикл while, в котором применять алгоритм Эвклида: встроенной функцией находить минимальный элемент, и вычитать его из максимального в куче, перестраивать кучу. И так до тех пор пока элементы в куче не станут равны между собой. Узнать когда это случится можно так: сравнить минимальный и первый элемент в куче.

Comment: эм... вот не надо так делать. Кучу ещё использовать где она совсем не нужна.